# flutter plugin issue in GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, zoom-sdk

```
D:\1111\zoom\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:5: error: package io.flutter does not exist
import io.flutter.Log;
                 ^
D:\1111\zoom\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:7: error: package io.flutter.embedding.engine does not exist
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
                                  ^
D:\1111\zoom\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
  public static void registerWith(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
                                           ^
  symbol:   class FlutterEngine
  location: class GeneratedPluginRegistrant
D:\1111\zoom\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:19: error: package com.evilratt.flutter_zoom_sdk does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new com.evilratt.flutter_zoom_sdk.FlutterZoomSdkPlugin());  
                                                                      ^
D:\1111\zoom\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
      Log.e(TAG, "Error registering plugin flutter_zoom_sdk, com.evilratt.flutter_zoom_sdk.FlutterZoomSdkPlugin", e);
      ^
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             12.6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```